# converting column data into column name

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my table "sample1"

```
Title          Frequency   Month1      Month2     Month3  Month 4
tution_fee      monthly     april        may       june    july
net_fee         monthly     april        may       june    july
misc            annually    april        may       june    july
```

I should get a table like this

```
tution_fee    net_fee      misc
april        april        april
may          may          may       
june         june         june
july         july         july
```

"sample1" table increases as i add data to it.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: SELECT month1 AS tution_fee, month2 as net_fee, month3 as misc FROM YourTable gives what you want. Are you sure that exactly what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PIVOT`

As you didn't mention you specific DBMS we cannot really give you a proper answer.

But with little research you'll find your needs with PIVOT.

Comment: i failed to get the proper answer

Comment: Database used is MsSql